# how to write get method using ng resource

Tags: angularjs

hi in my requirement i tried to write post method using ngresource but now i want to change that into get method. can anyone help me to solve this problem. i am new to angularjs thanks in advance

```
$scope.clickresult = {};
        var Call = $resource('../api/Home', {}, { query: { method: 'POST', isArray: true} });
        $scope.click = function () {
            //alert("hi");            
            $scope.selected = "";
            var x = $('#txtSearch').val();
            var _ReqObj = new Object();
            _ReqObj.id = x;
            _ReqObj.Meth = "CD";
            // alert(x);
            Call.query({}, _ReqObj,
                        function (response) {
                            if (response == '') {
                                // alert('no data');
                                window.location.replace("#/");
                            }
                            else {
                                //alert("daata");
                                $scope.message = response;
                            }
                        },
                                    function (error) {
                                        window.location.replace("#/");

                                    }
                                 );
        };
```

Comment: You were asking this question three times in a row. Please close two of the questions and only leave one open.

Comment: because that much important this question

Comment: I understand you want an answer. Please try to read the documentation thoroughly first before asking: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: If you have a bit of time we can move this to chat and I can try to help you.

Comment: thanks for respond. but i don't know where the chat application is in this site. will u help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some initial help so you can solve your future problems on your own.

**1. Use developer tools** to see errors, requests and responses: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Open the tools from the menu or use cmd+alt+I on Mac or ctrl+shift+I on Windows.

In the "Network" tab of the developer tools you can see the communication with your server (E.g. request method = GET, response from the server). In the "Preview" tab you can see the json the server sent you. Tell me if you have problems finding this, because it is very important to find bugs in your code.

**2. Use logging!**

In angular you can add $log to your code and with $log.log("message", object) you can output debug messages and the current state of objects from your code. You can see the logging messages in the developer tools in the "Console" tab.

**3. Read the documentation**

Angular provides documentation and examples for their functions. Read this about the $resource service https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Read about the difference between GET and POST method.

**4. Try a simple example** from a tutorial and try to adapt it to your needs

Copy a simple resource example from the internet and make it work. If that works change it step by step until it is what you need.

**5. For your example**:

How does your server side script work? In your question I can only see the angular code. If you want to use the GET method the server has to provide a function that reacts to GET.

The $resource service already provides a query method:

```
{ 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };
```

Normally you don't need to add "{ query: { method: 'POST', isArray: true}" to your code. The query function is already there!

To send a GET request with the query function you just need:

```
var Call = $resource('../api/Home', {});
```

Now open your developer tools, go to the Network tab and then execute the function $scope.click in your website. What do you see in the Network tab? The request should be fired with "request method: GET". What is the answer from the server? The problem is maybe not in your angular code but in your server code.

Try these things and tell me if you need more help.

Comment: no. my web api was the main problem. so now i am changing my web api